# Why lazy init entity is null when assigned to DTO inside transaction boundary?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am porting my legacy code to spring boot + angular application, which was spring + angular js earlier. My pojo has @ManyToOne relationship in it which is lazy. 
When i try to create a DTO object from original object, the child object inside orginal object is null, when sent to client. In my legacy application same code works perfectly.

If i make it eager or i call sysout on that child element before creating DTO then it works, probably because getters of child object is called internally.

Parent object

```
public class ComponentInfo implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1135710750835719391L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="TAGGING_KEY")
    private String taggingKey;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPONENT_CONFIG_ID",nullable = true)
    private ReportComponentConfig componentConfig;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 200)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "ORIGINAL_FILE_NAME",length=50)
    private String originalFileName;

    @Column(name = "OVERRIDE_DOCUMENT")
    private Boolean overrideDocument = false;

    @Column(name = "START_DATE")
    private Date startDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="componentInfo",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<TransactionComponentInfo> transactionComponentInfo = new ArrayList<>(0);

    @Column(name = "SHOW_GLOBAL")
    private Boolean showGlobal = false;
}
```

Child Object

```
public class ReportComponentConfig {

    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name = "COMPONENT_CONFIG_ID", table = "ID_GENERATOR", pkColumnName = "GEN_KEY", valueColumnName = "GEN_VALUE", pkColumnValue = "COMPONENT_CONFIG_ID", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "COMPONENT_CONFIG_ID")
    @Column(name = "COMPONENT_CONFIG_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "TAG", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String tag;

    @Column(name = "COMP_CONFIG", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(MAX)")
    private String config;

    @Column(name = "PUBLISHED_CONFIG", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(MAX)")
    private String publishedConfig;

    @Column(name = "IS_PUBLISHED")
    private boolean published = false;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPONENT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Component component;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "CONFIG_REPORT_MAPPING", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COMPONENT_CONFIG_ID"))
    @Column(name = "REPORT_ID")
    private Set<Long> reports = new HashSet<>(0);

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "CONFIG_TRANSACTION_MAPPING", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "COMPONENT_CONFIG_ID"))
    @Column(name = "TRANSACTION_ID")
    private Set<Long> transactions = new HashSet<>(0);

    @Column(name = "VIEWS", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(MAX)")
    private String views;
}
```

DTO

```
public class ComponentInfoDTO implements Cloneable {

    private ReportComponentConfig componentConfig;

    private String taggingKey;

    private String description;

    private String originalFileName;

    private Date startDate;

    private Boolean overrideDocument;

    private Boolean showGlobal;

    private ComponentInfoDTO parentComponentInfo;

    public ComponentInfoDTO() {
    }

    public ComponentInfoDTO(ComponentInfo ci, TransactionComponentInfo transactionComponentInfo) {
        this.componentConfig = ci.getComponentConfig();//this is object is null
        this.taggingKey = ci.getTaggingKey();
        this.description = ci.getDescription();
        this.originalFileName = ci.getOriginalFileName();
        this.startDate = ci.getStartDate();
        this.overrideDocument = ci.getOverrideDocument();
        this.showGlobal = ci.getShowGlobal();
        if (transactionComponentInfo != null) {
            this.parentComponentInfo = this.clone();
            this.startDate = transactionComponentInfo.getStartDate();
            this.overrideDocument = transactionComponentInfo.getOverrideDocument();
            this.description = transactionComponentInfo.getDescription();
            this.originalFileName = transactionComponentInfo.getOriginalFileName();
            this.showGlobal = true;
        }

    }
}
```

New Code image
[image]

Old Code image
[image]

Edit:
Both are same but in older case i get the child object on client side and in new case i get null.

This is the data i'm getting in my older application with lazy init

```
[ {
  "componentConfig" : {
    "id" : 3,
    "name" : "Monthly Origination By Region",
    "tag" : "CHART_monthlyOriginationByRegion",
    "config" : "xyz",
    "published" : true,
    "component" : {
      "id" : "CHART",
      "name" : "Chart",
      "defaultConfig" : null,
      "htmlTag" : "<chart></chart>",
      "filePath" : "chart/chart.component.js",
      "dependentScriptsSrc" : [ ],
      "dependencies" : null
    },
    "reports" : [ 3 ],
    "transactions" : [ 2 ],
    "views" : "{\"monthlyOriginationByRegion\": {\"key\": \"MONTHLY_ORIGINATION_BY_REGION\"}}"
  },
  "taggingKey" : "3",
  "description" : "asdfasd\nasdfadf",
  "originalFileName" : "Citi Tape - 2141 - GEBL0501 - 2019 Oct 04.xlsm",
  "startDate" : "2019-10-28T18:30:00.000+0000",
  "overrideDocument" : true,
  "showGlobal" : true,
  "parentComponentInfo" : null
} ]
```

This is the data in new application

```
[ {
  "componentConfig" : null,
  "taggingKey" : "3",
  "description" : "asdfasd\nasdfadf",
  "originalFileName" : "Citi Tape - 2141 - GEBL0501 - 2019 Oct 04.xlsm",
  "startDate" : "2019-10-28T18:30:00.000+0000",
  "overrideDocument" : true,
  "showGlobal" : true,
  "parentComponentInfo" : null
} ]
```

Component config should not be null, if make it eager fetch it works in new app but in my older application, it is working with lazy fetch.

Comment: `private int id;` primitive cannot be null. Your old code use wrapper type `Integer`

Comment: Oh sorry, i completely ignored that, but still why lazy init object is null in new case.

Comment: How do you load your entity (or the DTO) from the database? Could you please post your DAO for this?

Comment: I am just using find all method of jpa repository, then i am iterating over every record and converting it to DTO.

Comment: 1. What exactly is your question? 2. What *exactly* do you think is null that shouldn't be.

Comment: @AlanHay i've added more details.

Comment: *this.componentConfig = ci.getComponentConfig();//this is object is null* The *enity* is clearly  not null as can be seen in the debugger. So if it is null in your DTO then the issue lies in your code and has nothing at all to do with the JPA/repsitory tier

Comment: Additionally, why create 'half a Dto' i.e. a DTO for the top level entity which wraps an Entity. Why no Dto fpr ReportComponentConfig?

Comment: If my code has problem then why eager fetch is giving me correct result, even if i put sysout statement in dto(another wrong way of eager fetch), then i get the desired result. As i told earlier the same code is working fine in non jpa hibernate environment. Between i have tweaked  my child class a little bit. I've added a composite class, without that i was getting constraint violation exception. I may be missing a tiny thing, that why i am facing this problem, but i was unable to catch it.

Comment: The reason, i've made half dto, i wanted parent to be support child object. If child object is absent for a transaction, i needed the parent object as fallback object. If someone edits child object inside transaction, then i save child object(which overrides that parent object for that transaction only). I should have made dto for Report component config but i am using that object at some place. So, i decided to make a single dto for both use case.

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the debugger window is a HibernateProxy. The fields of that proxy are never initialized! The getters are intercepted and delegated to the loaded entity which is located somewhere inside the proxy.

This means you have to never call fields directly, as you don’t know if the object is a proxy or your loaded entity. You always need to work on the getters.

How are you mapping the entity to the DTO? Most likely you use field access, while you should use the getters.

Comment: I am calling the getters for component config(not the properties inside it) as you can see in DTO. I am just passing the parent component to DTO Constructor, which is component Info and setting each properties in DTO by calling getter of original object.